# mongoDB findAndModify error - nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm running into an error when I'm trying to run the findAndModify() method on a mongoDB database on Node.

The error I'm getting is:

> [MongoError: exception: must specify remove or update]

Which I find weird as I've specified 'update', my code is as follows.

```
var techId = req.params.id,
    collection = db.collection('tech');

collection.findAndModify({
    query: { _id: techId},
    update: { $inc: { score: 1 } }
}, function(err, doc){
    console.log(err, doc);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the syntax wrong, there are too much objects.

Try:

```
db.collection('tech').findAndModify(
    {_id: techId}, // query
    {$inc: { score: 1 }}, // update
    function(err, object) {
        console.log(err, doc);
    }
);
```

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure you also have to have the sort parameter as the second argument. That's to satisfy the library, not Mongo.